# Периодические проблемы с подключением

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть вот такой код, через который я общаюсь с сервером.

```
Socket(host, port).use { socket ->
    socket.soTimeout = timeout

    BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())).use { out ->
        out.write(message)
        out.flush()
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).use { inp ->
            return inp.readLine()
        }
    }
}
```

Периодически тестовый планшет перестаёт работать с сетью, хотя подключение есть и вай-фай стабилен. Увидел сейчас в логах

```
W/TransactionService: [1][LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run>864]  ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() action: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, mobileDataEnable= mConnMgr=null
W/TransactionService: [1][ActivityThread.handleStopService>2912]  Destroying TransactionService
W/TransactionService: [1][ActivityThread.handleCreateService>2749]  Creating TransactionService
W/TransactionService: [1][LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run>864]  ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() action: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, mobileDataEnable= false
W/TransactionService: [1][ActivityThread.handleStopService>2912]  Destroying TransactionService
```

Погуглил, везде пишут про BroadcastChannel, но я его не использую.

Это вообще на моей стороне проблема, или что-то не так с устройством?

---

Короче, насколько я понял, это рили проблемы определённого устройства.

Comment: Думаю, стоит проверить на другом устройстве.

Comment: А какую билиотеку вы используете? Предположу что у вас нет обработки ситуаций disconnect, и т.д., должен быть код который это делает:

В частности обрабатывать:
connect_error. Fired upon a connection error.
Parameters:
Object error object

connect_timeout. Fired upon a connection timeout.